# CloudFormation template file -- how to use ref function in the middle of a string to reference a parameter

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, formatting, aws-cloudformation

How do you dereference a parameter in the middle of a string?

I have a JSON Cloudformation template file that takes a parameter for a S3 bucket name ("BucketName") to use in an IAM policy that gives permission to that bucket -- policy below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::${Ref:BucketName}/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

`"arn:aws:s3:::${Ref:BucketName}/"` doesn't work;

`"arn:aws:s3:::", {"Ref": "BucketName"}, "/"` also doesn't work because it reads it as a list of strings instead of a single string.

I know I could take the entire arn as a parameter instead of just the bucket name, but how would I be able to reference BucketName within the string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You need to use intrinsic functions to concatenate a static value with a `Ref` value.

[Fn::Join reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html)

In your case, this would lead to the following construct.

```
"Resource": [
   "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", {"Ref":"BucketName"}] ]
]
```

Comment: Bit late to the party, but I think you need a { and } around the Join function. i.e. "Resource": [
  { "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:s3:::", {"Ref":"BucketName"}] ] }
]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to comment on @jens answer, to show how it's being done in YAML format, but it is not readable so I will write it here as an answer:

```
  Resource: !Join
    - ''
    - - 'arn:aws:s3:::'
      - !Ref ReceivingFiles1
      - /*
```